# How to find the possible radices (bases) of two numbers such that they equal each other?

Tags: number-systems

For example, suppose we have two numbers $x, y \in$ N with their corresponding bases $a$ and $b$

$
x_{a} = y_{b}
$

How do you determine $a$ and $b$ such that the equation is satisfied?

I tried interpreting the problem as a equation, such that each digit in my numbers x and y are a coefficient. For example, I have the numbers $241$ and $27$, and my idea was that I try to solve the equation $2a^2+4a+1=2b+7$. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get past that.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. What have you tried?

Comment: Hey, I tried interpreting the problem as a equation, such that each digit in my numbers $x$ and $y$ are a coefficient. For example, I have the numbers $241$ and $27$, and my idea was that I try to solve an equation $2 * a^2 + 4 * a^1 + 1 * a^0 = 2*b^1 + 7*b^0$. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get past that.

Comment: Adamt, add what you wrote in the comment into the post.

Answer (score 1):

For small numbers you can often make progress with divisibility.  First note that $a^0=b^0=1$, so in your example we need 
$$2a^2+4a+1=2b+7\\2a^2+4a=2b+6\\a^2+2a=b+3\\b=a^2+2a-3$$
and you can choose any $a$ you want greater than $4$ and compute $b$.  This will duly make $b \gt 7$.  When the numbers have three digits you will get quadratic equations, which allow you to require that the square root be integral.  Similarly here, if we wanted to start from $b$ we would find $$(a+1)^2=b+4\\a=\sqrt{b+4}-1$$ so we must choose $b$ to be four less that a square.  We need $a\gt 4$, so $b \ge 32$

Comment: Hey Ross, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I don't yet fully understand why I should choose $a > 4$ in this example. Could you perhaps explain?

Comment: Because you have a $4$ in the base $a$ expansion, so $a$ must be at least $5$ to allow that.  Similarly we must have $b \gt 7$, but given the limit on $a$ that is always satisfied.